# Split method to divide the address into street, city, state, and zip code and display only the street and city segments

Tags: c#, split

This is what I've been asked: 
Use a Split method to divide the address into street, city, state, and zip code and display only the street and city segments

What is my error?
Address format: 123 ABC Dr, Omaha, NE 12345
Here is my code: (It only shows the street number).

```
/*Address code now*/
            Console.Write("\n\nWhat's your university address:");
            string strUAAaddress = (Console.ReadLine());


            /*divide the address into street, city, state, and zip code. display only the street/city*/
            strUAAaddress=strUAAaddress.Trim();
           if (strUAAaddress.StartsWith(" "))
                strUAAaddress = strUAAaddress.Remove(0, 1); 
          string[] addressParts = strUAAaddress.Split(' '); //strUAAaddress.Split(' ');
          string street = addressParts[0];
          string state = addressParts[2];
          string city = addressParts[1];
          string zipCode = addressParts[3];

          Console.WriteLine(street); Console.Write(city); Console.Write(zipCode); Console.Write(state);
```

Comment: What is `strUAAaddress` for example. Can you give an example?

Comment: If you split by a space, you will get 6 substrings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the address format, the delimiters are `,` and space character. Can try the following code

```
strUAAaddress=strUAAaddress.Trim();

string[] addressParts = strUAAaddress.Split(',');

string street = addressParts[0];
string city = addressParts[1];
string stateZip = addressParts[2];
```

Here we get the street, city and the combination of state and zip code.
The `stateZip` comprises of state and zip code, we need to split further based on the space character delimiter.

```
string []data = stateZip.Split(' ');
string state = data[0];
string zip = data[1];
```